# Python 3.X: Call Outside Variable In Nested For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've nested one `for` loop inside of another. The first loop simply iterates over the second loop five times; the second loop iterates over the same simple block of code five times.

In total, these loops should perform the same job twenty-five times.

```
x = 0

for y in range(0, 5,):
    for z in range(0, 5,):
        print(str(int(x + 1)) + ". Hello")
```

I expected the output to be:

```
1. Hello.
2. Hello.
3. Hello.
4. Hello.
5. Hello.
```

Twenty-five times, with each proceeding line increasing the number's value by one.

Instead, the output was:

```
1. Hello
```

This output *repeated itself twenty-five times.* How do I fix this problem and receive the output I want?

Comment: The number never changes because you never increment `x`

Comment: To be clear, you do add 1 to `x` in `int(x + 1)` but you don't store the result in `x`. Like some of the answers are suggesting, by separating the computation and storage `x = x + 1` or `x += 1` from printing the result `print(str(x) + ". Hello")`, you solve the problem. Some languages would allow you to do the whole thing in one go, but using the assignment in Python looks just like assigning a value to a named parameter, so `print(x = x + 1)` confuses Python and isn't very clear to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't updating the value for `x` as you loop through.

Try this:

```
x = 0

for y in range(0, 5,):
    for z in range(0, 5,):
        x+=1
        print(str(x) + ". Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just add one extra line

```
x = 0

for y in range(0, 5,):
    for z in range(0, 5,):
        print(str(int(x + 1)) + ". Hello")
        x += 1
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't realize I had to separately modify the variable's value when using it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this :

```
   i = 0
for y in range(0, 5):
    for z in range(0, 5):
        i = i+1
        print(str(i) + "." " Hello.")
```